# Windows 7 Professional - Dymo 450 Turbo Printer Errors Then Prints - Need To View Error Details

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printing, printer

We use `Dymo 450 Turbo` printers with over 200 computers we support. I have two computers that a customer has that is having issues. The hardware of the systems seem to be refurbished computers and are running `Windows 7 Professional x64`. When I print, there is an intermittent delay, which can be up to 20 seconds. These print jobs are very small (think 2" x 1" label) and should be instantaneous.

We use this printer with our software at many locations, however this location has the same issue with the 2 computers.

I've downloaded the latest software drivers from dymo. I tested both x64 and x86 drivers (so `program files` vs `program files (x86)`). Both have the same issue, where sometimes it prints right away and sometimes it has a long delay before it prints. When it has the delay, you can see a error show up in the print status and then a couple seconds later, it clears and everything prints.

[image]

After the error, then it processes quickly, like it should normally. Then consecutive prints happen quickly. If you let the system sit for a while, then it repeats where the first print takes forever does the error then follow up prints happen quickly.

I went into the power settings, and set everything to maximum performance, so there is no sleeping issues.

I've tried to tweak the driver setting to reduce enhanced printing and just do basic things, as that is all we need for the printing, but no luck with that helping solve the issue.

I'm trying to find out more details about the error when it occurs, to see if it is something I can fix, or identify if there is an underlying hardware/driver issue with the print spooling. Is there a way to watch a windows log when the error occurs and get more details and determine what the underlying issue is?

**UPDATE:**

I got the following steps from http://smallbusiness.chron.com/check-printer-logs-54952.html which gives me access to the print job error...

**Using the Event Viewer**

**Step 1**

Log in to the computer or server where the printer driver is installed using an administrator account. In smaller environments, this is the computer with the physical connection to the printer.

**Step 2**

Click "Start," type "eventvwr” (without quotation marks) in the Search box and press “Enter.”

**Step 3**

Expand “Applications and Services Logs,” and then expand “Microsoft.”

**Step 4**

Expand “Windows” and “PrintService.”

**Step 5**

Click the “Operational” log. If enabled, you should see a list of print jobs and print events, such as the removing/adding of printers. If the log is blank, it’s not enabled. Right-click on “Operational” and select “Enable log” to log all future print jobs.

[image]

What is interesting is that I don't see an error in this screen. I assume the `0x0` is the no error messsage, which is why the Level is showing as information instead of as an error... Any ideas on how to get better logging to see what the real error was/is?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the details you have included in regards to the problem you are experiencing.

I have had some talks with our developers in regards to this error and what we would like is if you could go to the same log as before and click on the details field then take a screenshot of everything in there.

This will allow for further research from our developers.

As well, we would like you to do an SFC /Scannow as I am sure you are familiar with, if not you can find more information [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833)

As the error in and of itself points to a problem with the print spooler inside of Windows and a system file checker will allow us to see if this is indeed the case.

I will be monitoring this thread to follow-up once we have your information or more information from our developers.

With best regards,
Jesper K
DYMOSupport